# C# recursive method converting to loop

Tags: c#

I wrote this recursive method but the problem is i need to do the same with a loop.
First one is recursive, and the second one is loop but it`s not good. Any advice how to fix the loop method?

```
double SR(int n)
{
    if (n > 1)
        return Math.Sqrt(2 + SR(n - 1)); 
    else    
        return Math.Sqrt(2);  
}//recursion



double SR2(double n)
{
    if(n > 1)
    {
        do
        {
            n = Math.Sqrt(2+Math.Sqrt(n - 1));
        }
        while(n <= 1);
    }
    else
    {
        n = Math.Sqrt(2);
    }

    return n; //loop
}
```

Comment: the output of both should be equal

Comment: It is not good because the output is not equal

Comment: "It's not good because it doesn't do what I want," isn't a great spot to start with a question about homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double SRloop(int n)
{
    var r = Math.Sqrt(2);

    for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        r = Math.Sqrt(2 + r);
    }

    return r;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it explains everything. And it gives me the same output.

Comment: A recursive method will always run once so this is not the same.

Answer (score 2):

Explaining Knaģis answer:

You need to grasp more the concept of recursive functions.

In general recursive functions have a notion of "base" or "stop" condition, that is, a "fixed" value the function returns when a specified condition is met, otherwise, it would continue indefinitely.

When converting to a loop, the base condition becomes the starting value of the loop. 
So in the looped version, Math.Sqrt(2) becomes the *starting* value of n.

From there, we loop until the desired value is achieved. How to determine when to stop? In the original recursive function, the stop condition is "n <= 1" (beware, its the condition for the "else" to be reached, so its the inverse of your if). Also, in each iteration, the function receives "n - 1" as argument. So what is happening is we are decrementing n by 1 until it reaches 1; so the loop will be executed (n - 1) times. To be more clear on this point, the loop could be rewritten with `for (var i = 0; i < (n-1); i++)` . The effect is the same and it is more clear that the loop executes (n-1) times.

Also, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20305824/1152602) for more info.